# opencv surf_cuda matcher error

Tags: c++, opencv

- OpenCV => 3.1.0
- Operating System / Platform => Windows 10 / x64
- Compiler => Visual Studio 2013

#### Detailed description

I wrote my code based on the example given on opencv github page for SURF matcher using CUDA.

When I try to build, i get the following errors:

```
1>Testing.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct cv::Ptr<class cv::cuda::DescriptorMatcher> __cdecl cv::cuda::DescriptorMatcher::createBFMatcher(int)" (?createBFMatcher@DescriptorMatcher@cuda@cv@@SA?AU?$Ptr@VDescriptorMatcher@cuda@cv@@@3@H@Z) referenced in function main
1>Testing.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl cv::cuda::SURF_CUDA::SURF_CUDA(void)" (??0SURF_CUDA@cuda@cv@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function main
1>Testing.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __cdecl cv::cuda::SURF_CUDA::defaultNorm(void)const " (?defaultNorm@SURF_CUDA@cuda@cv@@QEBAHXZ) referenced in function main
1>Testing.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl cv::cuda::SURF_CUDA::downloadKeypoints(class cv::cuda::GpuMat const &,class std::vector<class cv::KeyPoint,class std::allocator<class cv::KeyPoint> > &)" (?downloadKeypoints@SURF_CUDA@cuda@cv@@QEAAXAEBVGpuMat@23@AEAV?$vector@VKeyPoint@cv@@V?$allocator@VKeyPoint@cv@@@std@@@std@@@Z) referenced in function main
1>Testing.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl cv::cuda::SURF_CUDA::downloadDescriptors(class cv::cuda::GpuMat const &,class std::vector<float,class std::allocator<float> > &)" (?downloadDescriptors@SURF_CUDA@cuda@cv@@QEAAXAEBVGpuMat@23@AEAV?$vector@MV?$allocator@M@std@@@std@@@Z) referenced in function main
1>Testing.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl cv::cuda::SURF_CUDA::operator()(class cv::cuda::GpuMat const &,class cv::cuda::GpuMat const &,class cv::cuda::GpuMat &,class cv::cuda::GpuMat &,bool)" (??RSURF_CUDA@cuda@cv@@QEAAXAEBVGpuMat@12@0AEAV312@1_N@Z) referenced in function main
1><computer_dir>\TestCode\x64\Debug\TestCode.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 6 unresolved externals
```

All libraries seem to be linked properly and I am not getting any error while writing the code.

It would be great if anyone could say what the error is. Thanks!

Comment: "All libraries seem to be linked properly" -> they seem to be not. As you provide no information about your build, it is not really possible to help you

Comment: What information do you need about the build?

I built opencv 3.1.0 with CUDA enabled and opencv_contrib modules. Even simple test code to know build information gives errors.

#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    printf("%s\n", cv::getBuildInformation().c_str());
    return 0;
}

This program gives a lot of errors! For example:

opencv_core310d.lib(system.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ippicvInit referenced in function "public: __cdecl cv::ipp::IPPInitSingelton::IPPInitSingelton(void)" (??0IPPInitSingelton@ipp@cv@@QEAA@XZ)

Comment: Describe your build exactly, as in what steps do you perform in order to build your program. Include all relevant code and compiler's and linker's flags.